# É possivel modificar qualquer jogo?

Tags: java, android

Será possível modificar uma ação ou adicionar algum objeto novo em qualquer jogo utilizando java?

Por exemplo: adicionar um novo monstro ao jogo, adicionar propriedades, aumentar velocidade do jogador, vida etc.

Comment: Olá. Seja bem-vindo. Está falando em modificar um jogo existente ou modificar um jogo seu?

Comment: modificar um jogo existente :)

Comment: Possível sim, viável não, modificar jogos existentes será necessário engenharia reversa e depois saber programar, fora que seria necessário a documentação do desenvolvedor do jogo pra se guiar no que foi feito. "Engenharia reversa" pode ser considerado ilegal e realmente se coloque no lugar do desenvolvedor do game, gostaria que alguém manipulasse o que você fez sem a sua permissão?

Comment: Pode usar a [**JNA**](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna) para isso. Um tempo atrás eu escrevi um Injetor de dll com essa biblioteca aí. Era só um `writeProcessMemory` mas acho que é a mesma ideia do que você está buscando, ler e escrever valores em memória.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível mas não é prático. Você precisaria usar um descompilador para obter o código Java a partir do APK.

Um possível impedimento é que o jogo não é feito apenas em Java. É muito comum dentre os jogos feitos usando motores de terceiros (praticamente todos os jogos profissionais) que o jogo use código nativo (C ou C++).

Mesmo que o jogo (ou a parte que te interessa) seja feito em Java, muito provavelmente o código foi ofuscado, usando uma ferramenta como o ProGuard. Um código ofuscado é um código modificado para perder completamente o significado para quem está lendo.

Uma abordagem mais promissora é modificar diretamente os valores na memória. É assim que ferramentas como o GameShark (lembra?) funcionam. Mas, para isso, é preciso acesso de super usuário (root), código nativo (Java não vai funcionar) e conhecimento de programação de baixo nível e Linux.

Eu nunca fiz isso, então não vou arriscar um exemplo, mas parece ter no [StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852672/scanning-and-editing-android-app-memory-values-programmatically). Se tiver curiosidade, dê uma olhada.

Comment: entendo,obrigado pela atenção :)

Comment: vou dar uma olhado no stackoverflow dos gringos.

Comment: Certo. Se a resposta respondeu à sua pergunta, não se esqueça de votar e marcar como aceita.